# How can we create an object of path when it is interface not class?

Tags: java, interface, nio

```
Path path=Paths.get("...."); //Path interface not class
```

**Another question:**
Do we need to implement all the methods of path interface listed in the java oracle documentation when we create a class which implements the path interface ?

Comment: `Paths.get` does `return new MagicPathImpl()`.

Comment: 1) That method returns instance of class which implements Path interface (you can't instantiate interface, you can instantiate only classes - non-abstract ones), 2) yes, non-abstract class must ensure that all methods will know how to behave, so it needs to provide or inherit from somewhere their implementation.

Comment: @Pshemo Does that means that the description of methods shown in the path interface page in oracle documentation  is actually the method implementation done in the instance of class which implements Path interface ?

Comment: To be able to use `InterfaceName reference = new SomeClass();` (like `List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();`) it must be ensured that any `reference.method()` can be safely called (where `method()` belongs to `InterfaceName`). This means that `SomeClass` must *provide* implementation for any `method()`.